# CPU Core Temperature 40 degrees cooler than CPUTIN tempterature

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature, intel-core-i7

My PC has been heat crashing due to an overheated CPU (Intel i7 4820k) a lot recently. I opened it up to redo the thermal paste and confirm that was not the issue.

I booted back up and monitored with CPUID HWMonitor and my package temperature is around 50°C, but the CPUTIN temperature (which is the temperature that was displayed in the BIOS), was 90°C.

[image]

What could cause this, and how could I fix it?

Comment: What did you change? Any hardware or firmware or so on?

Comment: No updates since the temperature spike. Just happened to get on one day and it started crashing. I had upgraded my GPU to a GTX 970 about two months prior, but that's the only change I've made that I can remember recently.

Comment: I usually couldn't to rely the third party applications, so 1-please be sure that your cpu fan installed correctly (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3kYR4cZG_0). 2-Please, reset your bois properties. 3-Please Upgrade your main board firmware.

Comment: Likely the program you are using doesn't understand how to read your motherboard's sensor correctly. If the cores are cool, the CPU is being cooled appropriately.

Comment: When your PC crashes, do you get a BSOD?